# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError - each time I try to run a test

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Am using Django 1.9.1 and testing using a Vagrant VM (Debian/Jessie64) hosting a Postgres db (version 9.4.5).

I've started sketching out my models and the site is functioning ok - adding records via the Admin interface is fine, etc, but every time I try to run the most basic of tests, I am getting the following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "contacts_person" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ion_id", "contacts_person"."directed_person" FROM "contacts_...
```

models.py:

```
class Person(models.Model):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    organisation = models.ForeignKey('contacts.Organisation', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    directed_person = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s'% (self.first_name, self.last_name)


class Mode(models.Model):

    mode = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.mode


class OrgType(models.Model):

    type = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    mode = models.ForeignKey('contacts.Mode', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.type


class Organisation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    [--fields--]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My test at this stage is simply:

```
class ModelCreationTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        Person.objects.create(first_name='Kimo', last_name='Rance', organisation=1, directed_person=True)
        Organisation.objects.create(
        name = 'Orgname',
        type = 'Orgtype',
        [--fields, etc--]
    )

    def test_is_a_person(self):
        p = Person()
        self.assertIsInstance(p, Person)
```

I've seen historical references to this from Googling that indicate it might have been a bug in earlier versions of Django, particularly with PostgreSQL, but can't seem to find a reasonable solution. Any further help much appreciated.

**Including output from ./manage.py migrate --verbosity=2** following comment by knbk:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: contenttypes, contacts, sessions, admin, auth
Running pre-migrate handlers for application admin
Running pre-migrate handlers for application auth
Running pre-migrate handlers for application contenttypes
Running pre-migrate handlers for application sessions
Running pre-migrate handlers for application bootstrap3
Running pre-migrate handlers for application contacts
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
Running post-migrate handlers for application admin
Running post-migrate handlers for application auth
Running post-migrate handlers for application contenttypes
Running post-migrate handlers for application sessions
Running post-migrate handlers for application bootstrap3
Running post-migrate handlers for application contacts
```

Similar when trying when adding a field to a model. Doesn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: What database are you using when you run test?

Comment: Thanks for responding. Get this: Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Got an error creating the test database: database "test_tokn" already exists

Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_tokn', or 'no' to cancel: <-- so assuming Django is creating a new database for me.

Comment: You might already created a test database but didn't clean it up. Django has documentation about test database: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database. Also, I think using sqlite3 would be a better option, because it's in memory database and never pollute your actual database.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Have switched to sqlite3 for now in development and tests are running without the error. Couldn't find any evidence of the old test db in postgres - don't know what was going on there. Thanks for your help. Leaving this open in case someone can help re postgres.

Comment: It's a bad idea to run tests on sqlite3, it'll just hide these errors instead of urging you to fix them. You _will_ run into the same problems when you try to deploy on a clean database. Can you show the migrate output when running the tests with `--verbosity=2`?

Comment: Thanks. Have added with `--verbosity=2` switch to original question, but this is on the original postgresql db. Not sure how to do this for test_db?

Comment: Ok, something interesting. On the advice of knbk, I have switched back to using Postgres on the VM and now, without making any other changes, the tests seem to be working normally. Very strange.